# Search for specific words inside one cell and write retrieved searched result in other cell

Tags: regex, search, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**Need help for following use case:**

**-** I have three columns, one named "Issue", second "Client" and the last one "Tags"

**-** Columns "Issue" and "Tags" are filled automatically after CSV. file import, where each cell of Tags column may contain multiple tags, but none of the Tag cells can contain multiple client tags

**-** Column "Clients" needs to be determined based on "Tags" column, and this is where I suck :(

[image]

---

**Basically, I want to insert a formula into "Clients" column that will do the following:**

1) Search for all possible client tags (Client A, Client B, Client C, Client D and Client E) in "Tags" column.

2) Retrieve if client tag is found and write that tag in the corresponding cell inside Client column.

**Wished output:**

[image]

In my opinion, the formula has to be generic to suits all Client cells, meaning formula, in my opinion, should contain all clients at once (A,B,C,D,E) and check if one of the clients is found and write that client. What is searched and found should be written as it is.

I tried smth like this:

```
=iferror(if(search({"Client A","Client B", "Client C", "Client D", "Client E"},J7,1)>0,"?????","no client"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if tag column contains line breaks you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D16:D, "(.*)\n")))
```

[image: 0]

---

otherwise, you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D16:D, 
 "Client A|Client B|Client C|Client D")))
```

[image]